# Validate the type of mongoengine.Dictfield values

Tags: python, mongoengine

I have a custom document like this one:

```
import mongoengine

class MYDOC(mongoengine.Document):
  ...
  intValuesDict = mongoengine.DictField()
  StringsListValuesDict = mongoengine.DictField()
  ...
```

When a document is about to be added in DB, I want mongoengine accept it and save it only if the values of **intValuesDict** field are integers and the values of **StringsListValuesDict** field are lists of strings.

Examples:

For this document it should raise an error and the document should not be saved in DB, because **StringsListValuesDict** has a value which is not list of strings (`[12, 13]`).

```
{
  ...
  intValuesDict: {
                   "key1": 12,
                   "key2": 13
                 }
  StringsListValuesDict: {
                   "key_1": [12, 13],
                   "key_2": ["abc", "def"]
                 }
  ..
}
```

Also error for this one because a value of **intValuesDict** is not integer (`"12"`):

```
{
  ...
  intValuesDict: {
                   "key1": "12",
                   "key2": 13
                 }
  StringsListValuesDict: {
                   "key_1": ["12", "13"],
                   "key_2": ["abc", "def"]
                 }
  ..
}
```

This document should be accepted and saved because `12` and `13` from **intValuesDict** are integers and `["12", "13"]` and `["abc", "def"]` from **StringsListValuesDict** are lists of strings:

```
{
  ...
  intValuesDict: {
                   "key1": 12,
                   "key2": 13
                 }
  StringsListValuesDict: {
                   "key_1": ["12", "13"],
                   "key_2": ["abc", "def"]
                 }
  ..
}
```

A solution is to create a function which validates the types of the dicts values before saving them into DB, but I want to know if mongoengine can do this for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Mongoengine docs say is -

> "Often, an embedded document may be used instead of a dictionary –
>   generally this is recommended as dictionaries don’t support validation
>   or custom field types."

I think you should look into [Mongo DB Document validation](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/core/document-validation/)

And best idea could be write custom validation function. It should override `clean` method of your Document. If your input data does not fit for you - just raise `ValidationError`. Here is an [example](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/document-instances.html#pre-save-data-validation-and-cleaning).